# Issue extracting specific data with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am back with essentially a somewhat similar problem. I have now learnt that you cannot find elements that are in an iframe if you haven't switched to it, which helped a lot, but I seem to still have issues locating elements even though they are not in an iframe.

I also ask for any advice regarding my script in general, or how one would go about improving it. Yes, I will change the implicitwait to WebDriverWait, but besides that. Is it okay if a script is structured in this way, with task -> task -> task and so forth, or is it simply bad practice?

I don't really see how I would go about throwing in some objective-oriented programming, or what I would gain from it besides if I wanted to customise the script in a major way, besides of course the learning aspect.

In any case, here is the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import accandpass as login
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()
x = x.strftime("%d")

driver = browser=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://connect.garmin.com/modern/activities")

driver.implicitly_wait(2)

iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID, "gauth-widget-frame-gauth-widget")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

element = driver.find_element("name", "username")
element.send_keys(login.username)

element = driver.find_element("name", "password")
element.send_keys(login.password)

element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

element = driver.find_element("name", "search")
element.send_keys("Reading")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "unit")
print(element)
```

[image: The data window I need to extract]

So everything actually works fine so far, to my great surprise. The element gives off this: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0ef84b2e-e0af-4b0c-b04c-94d5371356c5", element="a70f4ee1-e840-457c-a255-4b2df603efec")> which wasn't really what I was looking for.

I am more looking for some check, to see that the element with name unit has the same date as x, which is today. So basically:

## Minutes read

minutes = 0
for i in element:
if element == x:
minutes += (element with time)

For loop to run through all the elements and check them all for the same date, and if the date matches then add the minutes read that day to the integer minutes for a sum of total minutes read today, for example.

Then do the same for the activities I will do, running, hiking and meditating.

Questions:

How do I get the integer from the element, so I can check it with x?
Is the for loop -> if statement -> add time from element a good solution to the case at hand?
Is it bad practice to structure a script this way, and how would you improve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: I took the part of the question where you were looking for the way to get the date off the page as the first question. The rest of your post concerning "Minutes read" and on is really a second question and should be moved to a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your question sounds like you want a code review. If you do, you'll want to post your code over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com but review their question requirements carefully before posting.

I think the main issue you are asking about is wanting to compare the date on the page to the current system date and you're getting some session and element GUIDs instead. You are printing the element object and not the contained text. You want

```
print(element.text)
```

or add an assert to compare it to the current system date in a specific format, something like...

```
assert element.text == datetime.today().strftime('%m %d')
```

---

Some quick additional feedback since you asked for some...

1. It sounds like you've already been informed that `.implicitly_wait()` is a bad practice and should be replaced with `WebDriverWait` for each instance where you need to wait.
2. If you aren't going to reuse a variable, don't declare one. In most cases you don't need to use one.

   ```
   element = driver.find_element("name", "username")
   element.send_keys(login.username)
   ```

   can be written

   ```
   driver.find_element("name", "username").send_keys(login.username)
   ```
3. If you are going to use variables, don't reuse the same name over and over, e.g. `element`. Give each variable a meaningful name so that the next person (or maybe yourself in a few weeks/months) will be able to more easily read and understand your code.

   ```
   element = driver.find_element("name", "search")
   element.send_keys("Reading")
   element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
   ```

   should instead be

   ```
   search = driver.find_element("name", "search")
   search.send_keys("Reading")
   search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
   ```
4. If you are going to continue writing scripts, do some reading on the page object model. Done right, it will clean up your code significantly, make maintenance much faster and easier, and make writing new scripts much faster. Basically you create a class for each page of the site and then add methods to the class for actions you need to take on the page.

   I don't have a garmin account so I can't log in but from the screenshot you posted you might have some methods like `.search_activities(string)`, `.get_search_results()`, `.filter_activities(string)`, etc. Once you've created those methods, they can be called repeatedly from the same script or many scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, not using variables would condense the code and remove a lot of unnecessary parts. I just didn't see the point in using another variable name considering I won't call the variable outside of that portion of the script anyhow? 

In any case, I should also definitely get into page object model for my next script. I just didn't see the point when I just want this specific data, and what I am going to call for will never change, wouldn't it then just be a lot of unnecessary work?

Comment: If this is a one-off script that you'll never use again, it may not be worth the work... BUT sometimes we create a script we think we'll never use again and then end up using it for future projects or coming back to update it later. Creating page objects really isn't that much more work once you understand the structure of it and ends up making things easier in the long run. Even if it's never used again, it's a good practice and it's good practice to do things the "right way" even if it's not a formal project.

Comment: Also, there's always the possibility that the garmin site will get updated soon. If you've used page objects, the maintenance is going to be easy or at least easier than if you didn't.

Comment: I have been trying a lot of different things but I don't seem to understand what the problem is. In any case, when I extract the element "unit", the date is wrong. The date is not the one in the html, "Aug 25", but today's date, which makes me unable to make a "x is equal to" and ensure that I get the correct data from the site?

Do you have any idea what could cause this? I have tried with XPATH as well, just in case it was the wrong "unit", but it didn't help either.

Comment: @Zeno Since this question has already been answered, I would put all the info for this new issue into a new question. Make sure you post the relevant HTML around the "unit" element so that we can verify the locator is pointing at the intended element, your current code, and the relevant error message or what specifically isn't working as expected.